# How to not validate certain inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, twitter-typeahead

I have a form where I'm using twitter typehead & the problem is whenever twitter typehead loads it creates another input field that is blank &not shown to user

Now i have this function to validate all inputs

```
 var fields = $('#second_step input[type=text]');
        var error = 0;
        if (!$("input[name='career']:checked").val()) {
  alert('Please Select yes or no'); return false;
}
        fields.each(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            if( value.length<1 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')]) {
                $(this).addClass('error');
                $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

                error++;  
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('valid'); 
            }
        });
        if (!$('#reg').valid()) {
    return false;
}
```

Now due to that typehead input whic has no name or id it just have a certain class `tt-hint` & this input is read only how can i just skip this input from my above validation?

Comment: You could, and probably should, skip/ignore fields that are disabled.  From your description this would include the tt-hint field.  After all, how can they correct an error on a field that is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery's NOT](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function.

`var fields = $('#second_step input[type=text]').not('.tt-hint');`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the fields with:

```
var fields = $('#second_step input[type=text]:not(.tt-hint)');
```

Comment: There are some select & radio button also but they don't get validate what should i add var fields to validate them also? till now i was doing this var fields = $('#first_step input[type=text], #first_step input[name=country]');

Answer (score 0):

Your input has typeahead applied by using a class selector `.typeahead`.
So in your case you could use the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class selector to filter them out:

```
var fields = $('#second_step input[type=text]:not(.typeahead)');
```

That way you skip the typeahead fields.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would ignore disabled fields, since the user cannot correct them if there is an error.  You say the input is read only so that would seem to correlate.

```
$('#second_step input[type=text]').filter(function(){ return !this.disabled; })
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
fields.each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if($(this).hasClass('tt-hint') {
            $(this).addClass('valid'); 
        } else {
        if( value.length<1 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')]) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

            error++;  
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('valid'); 
        }
       }
    });
    if (!$('#reg').valid()) {
return false;
}
```